# How to extract only the data points from BodePlot plot?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to fix the Phase plot part of BodePlot, as it does not wrap correctly. And there is no option that I can use to tell it to wrap.

So, instead of doing the full plot myself, (I can do that if I have to) I am thinking of first making the BodePlot, grab the data points, do the wrapping on the data (once I get the x,y data, the rest is easy), then I need to put the new list of points back into the plot, and then use Show to display it.

The part I am stuck at, is extracting the points from FullForm. I can't get the correct Pattern to do that.

This is what I go to so far:

```
hz=z/(z^2-z+0.3);
tf=TransferFunctionModel[hz,z,SamplingPeriod->2];
phasePlot=BodePlot[tf,{0.001,2 Pi},
       ScalingFunctions->{Automatic,{"Linear","Degree"}},PlotLayout->"List"][[2]]
```

[image]

You see how it does not wrap at 180 degrees. It is more common in dsp that Bode phase plot wraps. Here is what it 'should' look like:

[image]

So, this is what I did:

```
 FullForm[phasePlot]
Graphics[List[
  List[List[], List[], 
   List[Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], 
    Line[List[List[0.0010000243495554542, -0.2673870119911639], 
      List[0.0013659538057574799, -0.36521403872250247], 
      List[0.0017318832619595053, -0.46304207336414027],
      ....
```

I see the data there (the x,y) But how to pull them out? I tried this:

```
  Cases[FullForm[phasePlot], List[x_, y_] -> {x, y}, Infinity];
```

But the above matches in addition to the list of point, other stuff that I do not need.
I tried many other things, but can't get only the list of points out.

I was wondering if someone knows how to pull only the (x,y) points from the above plot. Is there a better way to do this other than using FullForm?

Thanks

**Update:**

I just find a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806034/extract-contours-from-contourplot-in-mathematica) which shows how to extract data from plot. So I used it:

```
   points = Cases[Normal@phasePlot, Line[pts_] -> pts, Infinity]
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `FullForm`. See my comments on David's answer. (I just noticed that you also used `FullForm` in the question.)

Comment: I do not have Mma 8 so I don't know about BodePlot.  However, Andrew Moylan (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287817/the-best-way-to-construct-a-function-with-memory/5288314#5288314)) has pointed out that `EvaluationMonitor`, together with Sow/Reap, may be used to 'cleanly' extract data points from `Plot`. This can be useful. For example, the following evaluates to True.  `Sort /@ Last@
   Reap[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, Sin[x]}]]] == 
 Cases[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}], x_Line :> First@x, Infinity]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do try nesting the replacement rules, for example

```
phase2 = phasePlot /. 
    Line[a_] :> (Line[a] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, Mod[y, 360, -180]});
Show[phase2, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-180, 180}}, FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

**Output:**

[image: BodePlot with wrapping]

Answer (score 3):

The list you are looking for appears to be wrapped by `Line[]`, and it seems to be the only case in your plot.  So you could use

```
Cases[phasePlot, Line[list_] :>  list, Infinity]
```

Edit:
When I posted my response, the page refreshed and I saw that you came across precisely what I had proposed. I'll leave my response posted here anyway.

Edit2: 
Szabolics pointed out that `FullForm[]` has no effect, so I removed it from my original posting.

Comment: `FullForm` is for printing the expression with a special formatting, it does not do anything useful in this `Cases`.  What you *might* need is `Normal` to expand any `GraphicsComplex` objects.

Comment: To clarify: In general, `FullForm` or any of the `*Form` functions never do any structural modification on the expression.  They simply affect the way it's printed.  What you see and what the kernel sees are not always the same.

Comment: @Szabolics.  Thanks for the clarification about `FullForm`.  I now dropped it from my posting.