# How to export ContourPlot3D surface and regenerate it in Excel, Originlab or some other similar softwares

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried this, but failed.

```
fig3D = ContourPlot3D[ x^2 + y^3 - z^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
                       PlotPoints -> 100]
pts = (InputForm@fig3D)[[1, 1, 1]];
ListSurfacePlot3D[pts]
```

The regenerated surface is very poor. Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: That is a very neat method for extracting points from `ContourPlot3D`.  Perhaps you would consider posting an answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7356699/499167) recent question, or to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6806034/499167) (earlier) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too bad if you specify `MaxPlotPoints`

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[pts, Mesh -> None, MaxPlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[pts]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Regarding the export to Excel, please consider that the Excel surface plot is a very basic construction and requires a matrix whose first file and column are the XY values with the  Z values in the inner cells. Example:

[image]

So, exporting a working dataset to Excel may require (an unspecified amount of) data  massaging.